# pulling a desired list from the maps

Tags: groovy

I have a map like below

> ["name1":["value1":"name1", "value2":"check1"],
>   "name2":["value1":"name2", "value2":" check2"],
>   "name3":["value1":"name3", "value2":" check3"]etc

I have a list with

> [name1, name2]

I would like to pull the list of all the "value2" for name1 and name2.

as

> [check1, check2]

Now I have changed the way I retrieve my values so it would be

> ["value1":"name1", "value2":"check1"], ["value1":"name2", "value2":"
>   check2"],["value1":"name3", "value2":" check3"]

how do I pull the the values now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pulling a field from a list based on second list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718985/pulling-a-field-from-a-list-based-on-second-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your map is in a variable called `map`. You can use the [`findResults`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#findResults%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method to find any entries where the key is in `list`. If it is, it adds that maps value2 entry.

```
def list = ['name1', 'name2']
def newList = []

newList = map.findResults { key, value ->
    if (key in list) { value['value2'] }
}

assert newList = [check1, check2]
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, but its not working for me. May be need to do something with the empty spaces before the "name1", it is " name1"

Comment: Why are there empty spaces? If you need to get rid of those, just call `.trim()` on the `String`. For for instance, `if (key.trim() in list)...`

Comment: Thanks for the response grant, I have changed my map to a list(edited question). how do I pull the required values now>#