# Pulling a field from a list based on second list

Tags: groovy

I have the following lists:

```
list1 = [["value1":"name1", "value2":"check1"], ["value1":"name2", "value2":" check2"],  
["value1":"name3", "value2":" check3"]]  
list2 = ['name1', 'name2']
```

I would like to pull the list of all the `"value2"` for `name1` and `name2`.
as:

```
[check1, check2]
```

Comment: I'm not sure about groovy, but in any language a `for` loop with an `if` statement would work. Have you tried that?

Comment: As I have huge number of records(hundreds of thousands), I am trying to find something which doesnt impact the performance. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
def list3 = list1.findAll { it.value1 in list2 }.value2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def list1 = [["value1":"name1", "value2":"check1"], ["value1":"name2", "value2":" check2"],

["value1":"name3", "value2":" check3"]]

def list2 =list1.collect{it."value2"}
```

Comment: Hi I would like to pull only values which are in the second list, not the whole list of values